# F# on SharpDevelop and command line arguments

Tags: command-line, f#, sharpdevelop

I was trying to use SharpDevelop 4.3 as an F# IDE.  I asked the question on the SharpDevelop forums but it's been a week and I've had no response.   Where exactly can I pass command line arguments to the program run through the IDE when I want to debug the program?  I went through the Project Options Menu items, and all the tabs contained, but I didn't identify a place for command line arguments.

I tried using Xavarin also, but it crashed immediately when I try to create an F# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The F# addin that is included with SharpDevelop does not currently have a way to set the command line arguments when you run your F# application. There is no Debug tab available in under project options. The only option available currently would be to modify the [source code](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/tree/master/src/AddIns/BackendBindings/FSharpBinding).